# When to factor duty cycle into power consumption calculations?

Tags: power-consumption, duty-cycle

This is probably a simple question for most of you.

I am calculating the power consumption of a device. The load is driven using a square PWM signal. At what point do I factor in the duty cycle? For now let's assume a 50% duty cycle with a starting voltage of 10 V, resistance of 1 ohm (for simple maths).

Currently the calcs look like.

- Effective Volts = 10 * 0.5 = 5 V.
- Watts = 5<sup>2</sup> / 1 = 25 watts.

Instead should I be doing:

- Watts = 10<sup>2</sup>/ 1 = 100 watts
- Effective watts = 100 * 0.5 = 50 watts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first calculation you are computing the average voltage when in fact this should be the RMS voltage. In your second calculation you are correctly calculating the power (one half cycle) and dividing by two to correctly get average power.

So, taking the average power of 50 watts and multiplying by 1 ohm then taking the square root delivers RMS voltage because: -

$$V = \sqrt{P.R} = 7.071 V$$

But you can calculate RMS voltage by squaring each voltage, taking the mean then square rooting: -

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{10^2 + 0^2}{2}} = 7.071V$$

If the duty cycle were 25% then it would be: -

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{10^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 + 0^2}{4}} = 5V$$

Notice how I've split the latter solution into 4 distinct time slots.

Comment: So am i correct in saying that we can use the the above calculated value for Watts. So Watts = (RMS Voltage)^2 / Resistance?

Comment: Correct, average power is RMS volts squared divided by resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The instantaneous power equals
$$ p(t)=\frac{v(t)^2}{R}$$
The average power (which is used as measure of power consumption) is
$$ P_{\text{avg}} = \frac{1}{T} {\int _0^T { p(t)\,dt} } $$
$$$$
$$  P_{\text{avg}} = \frac{1}{T} {\int _0^T { \frac{v(t)^2}{R}\,dt} } = \frac{1}{T} \Bigg( \int _0^{dc \cdot T} { \frac{v(t)^2}{R}\,dt} + \int _{dc \cdot T}^T { \frac{v(t)^2}{R}\,dt} \Bigg) $$
where dc is the duty cycle.
$$$$
Using \$V_{on} = 10 \text{ V and } V_{off} = 0 \text{ V}  \$

$$  P_{\text{avg}} = \frac{1}{T} \Bigg( \int _0^{dc \cdot T} { \frac{{V_{on}}^2}{R}\,dt} + \int _{dc \cdot T}^T { \frac{{V_{off}}^2}{R}\,dt} \Bigg) =  dc\frac{{V_{on}}^2}{R}$$
where dc is the duty cycle.